# Delphi Database Programming - universal location of database

Tags: database, delphi, ado

I'm using ADO connection to connect to my database is MS Access, and everything works fine, but I am curious if there is the option to write a "universal" location.

e.g. Instead of

**C**:\Documents and Settings\User

I want to write *something* instead of the **C** so the program would look at every other location where the Documents and Settings folder exist.

I tried with the asterisk (*:\Documents and Settings\User), and three dots (...:\Documents and Settings\User) but it doesn't work

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're really asking how to discover where the user's home directory is, rather than how to find all the root folders named *Documents and Settings*. The latter would be foolish: First, that specific name varies by Windows version and language, so whatever solution you find would be of limited use; second, on any given system, there shouldn't be more than one anyway.

Comment: Despite my answer below, there is no such thing as an "universal" location. Do you want to have one DB per user, or one for all users using this computer? Do you want to share the DB across a network share or only on the local machine? And finally, what about client-server DBs, like SQL Server, which is easily possible through ADO?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the curerent users' folder, the easiest way is to use `SHGetFolderPath()` with `CSIDL_PERSONAL` from `ShFolder.pas`:

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils, Shfolder, ComObj, Windows;

var buffer : array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  try
    OleCheck( SHGetFolderPath( 0, CSIDL_PERSONAL, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, buffer));
    Writeln(buffer);
  except
    on E: Exception do Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Among some other arguments, the function expects a `CSIDL` constant which determines the folder location to be returned. For example, if you want to place the DB under `C:\ProgramData\<Your application name here>`, you would use `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` instead.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out about the other arguments and other `CSIDL` constants.

Comment: +1 Just thought I'd mention that in newer versions of Windows the CSIDL_* stuff has been replaced by the "Known folders" concept. The equivalent function is now the [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx)